# Upload image, video file issue

Tags: php, mysql, html

Basically I want to upload image and Video file with an html form. Image is uploading but video file isn't, When I upload video file it's show progressing....Can't see anything.. What is the problem in my code, can anyone help me?

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']) == "Submit")
{   
$err = array(); 
@$filed = addslashes($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
@$img_named =    addslashes($_FILES['file']['name']);
@$img_sized = getimagesize($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
@$imgd = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']));

function getExtension($str)
    {
$i = strrpos($str,".");
if (!$i) { return ""; }
$l = strlen($str) - $i;
$ext = substr($str,$i+1,$l);
return $ext;
    }
$extension = getExtension($img_named);
$extension = strtolower($extension);
$image_named_uniq = uniqid().'.'.$extension;

$upload_path_dis = 'user/manage/discussionimg/';

$diss = $_POST['type'];
$sub = $_POST['sub'];
$msg = $_POST['msg'];
$date = "On " . date("F Y h:i:s A");


if (!isset($_SESSION['uname']))
$err[] = "You need to login";

else
{
$uname = $_SESSION['uname']; //session username

if(empty($sub) && empty($msg) && empty($filed))
$err[] = "All field required";
else
{
if(empty($sub))
$err[] = "Subject Requried";

if(empty($msg))
$err[] = "Message Requried";

if(empty($filed))
$err[] ="SORRY, you have to be upload a image";
else
{ 
if($img_sized == FALSE)
{
$err[] ="That's not an image";  
}
}
}
}


if(!empty($err))
{
foreach($err as $er)
{
echo "<font color=red>$er</font><br/>";
}
}

else
{
$sql= mysql_query("INSERT INTO discussion VALUES ('', '$imgd', '$image_named_uniq', '$diss', '$sub', '$msg', '$uname', '$date' ) ");
if(!$sql)
echo "Can't submit your discussion" . mysql_error();
if(!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],$upload_path_dis . $image_named_uniq))
{
die('File Not Uploading');
}
else
{
echo "Discussion was submitted";
print "<script>";
print " self.location='          "  .$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] . "        ';"; // Comment this line if you don't want to redirect
print "</script>";

}       
}       

}

?>

<form action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post" 
name="discussion" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<table width="240" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">

<tr>
<td><b>Select your image</b>
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="62914560"  />
<input type="file" name="file" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="width:230;"><b>Select your Discussion</b>
<select name="type" class="td">
<?php   
$sqld = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM distype");

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sqld))
{
$d_id = $row['d_id'];
$diss = $row['type'];
echo "<option value='$diss'>$diss</option>";
}
?>

</select></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><b>Subject</b></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="text" name="sub" value="" size="33" class="td"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><b>Message</b></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><textarea cols="30" rows="3" name="msg" class="td_text"></textarea></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="submit"><br>
<td></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove your `@` error inhibitors and you'll see what the problem is:

```
$filed = addslashes($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
$img_named =    addslashes($_FILES['file']['name']);
$img_sized = getimagesize($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
$imgd = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']));
```

This line of code gets the size of the image:

```
$img_sized = getimagesize($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
```

What happens when the image is a video file? You get an error.

To fix it, check whether the file is an image or a video file using MIME types or extensions (not recommended). If it's an image, get the size. If it isn't, don't get the size.

Comment: Well, When i upload a vedio file then it's show progressing...progressing.... after few minutes it's show a black page. I remove the @ error inhibitors and see following error..Warning: getimagesize() [function.getimagesize]: Filename cannot be empty in C:\xampp\htdocs\evantechbd\index2.php on line 280

Warning: file_get_contents() [function.file-get-contents]: Filename cannot be empty in C:\xampp\htdocs\evantechbd\index2.php on line 281.

Comment: Increase your script execution time or increase the max upload size (that's probably the error). Look [here](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/php/increase-maximum-php-upload-size/).

Comment: Maximum allowed size for uploaded files. to
upload_max_filesize = 124M

Comment: Also increse execution time 60 to 120

Answer (score 0):

If your intention is to protect with upload file size, do not use @$img_sized = getimagesize($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']); instead of that use this one

```
@$img_sized = $_FILES['file']['size'];
```

this will get file size for all file extensions, and also remove the line   @$img_sized = getimagesize($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']); this will give unreadable or warning for images and videos etc.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set some setting in php.ini file and if you dont wont do that than set .htaccess file to increase size

You get article here

http://sonalkhunt-technical.blogspot.com/